# What is the difference between while (x = false) and while (!x) in Java?

Tags: java, try-catch, while-loop

Sorry, I'm new to Java, so this question might be unclear.

I have been recently dealing with enclosing a try and catch statement in a while loop, because I wanted to make sure that getting input was enclosed from the rest of the program.

I have come across a problem where using an exclamation mark (!) in front of a variable in the while conditions (e.g. while (!done)) instead of using = false (e.g. while (done = false)) changes the way my program runs.

The former (!done) results in the try and except statements running as expected.
The latter (done = false) does not, simply skipping them and moving on to the next part of the code.

I was under the impression that ! before a variable meant the same thing as var = false.

Am I mistaken?

Here's an example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestOne {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;
        boolean inputDone = false;
        while (!inputDone) {
            try {
                System.out.print("Enter in a number here: ");
                num = input.nextInt();
                inputDone = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Success!");
    }
}
```

Currently, compiling and running the program will go smoothly: it will prompt me for a number, typing in a letter or really long number causes it to print out the exception type and exit. Typing in a normal number causes it to print Success!

On the other hand, if I were to replace !inputDone with inputDone = false, it simply prints out Success! when I run the program.

Can anyone explain the difference to me between the ! and the = false statements in a while loop?

Comment: x == false is bad style, almost as bad as x == true.

Comment: I love it that the typo in the question title is the reason for never writing `lvalue == false`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Note the difference between `done = false` and `done == false`. The first one *assigns* `done` to be `false` and evaluates as `false`, the second one compares `done` with `false` and is exactly identical to `!done`.

So if you use:

```
while (done = false)
{
 // code here
}
```

Then `done` is set to `false` and the code within the while loop doesn't run at all.

Comment: Thanks. That's the second error in recent times I've forgotten about that second exclamation mark.

Comment: @Mana: if you get out of the (BAD) habit of explicitly comparing booleans with '==', you won't make this mistake.

Answer (score 4):

The statement `x = false` is an assignment - you are setting x to false. The statements `x == false` and `!x` are the same, however. The statement `x == false` compares x to false and will be true if the value of `x` is false and false if the value of `x` is true. The statement `!x` will result in the negation of the value of `x`.

In your code, if you replace `while (!inputDone)` with `while(inputDone == false)`, you will get the expected behavior.

Comment: Ohh, haha. Wow, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `==` instead of `=` for comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

The expression:

```
x = false
```

means assign `x` the value `false`.

After this happens in your `while()`, it then evaluates `x`, which is `false` so it doesn't enter the loop at all.

On the other hand:

```
while (!x)
```

means "as long as !x is true, continue entering the loop". since `!x` means "the opposite of x".  So as long as `x` is false, the loop will continue

Answer (score 2):

"while(done = false)" is equals to "done=false; while(done)"

It should be written as "while(done == false)" or "while(false == done)".

But still , !done is the most readable code, it say "NOT DONE"

Comment: writing "while (done == false) ..." works best for me.  I tend to overlook those pesky exclamation marks.

Answer (score 2):

As many others have pointed out, you have typoed `==`. More interesting are the issues surrounding this.

For language designed: Encouraging side-effects in expressions is bad. Using the symbol `==` to represent mathematical `=` is not a good choice.

In terms of readability, `!done` reads much better than `done == false` - we want "not done" (better, IMO, would be "until done" instead of "while not done"). Although (perpetual) newbies often write the redundant `someCondition == true`.

It is a good idea to make variables `final`, although clearly not feasible in this situation. However, we can remove the flag entirely by using a break statement. A minority opinions follows a Single Entry Single Exit (SESE) rule, whereby `break` is banned, whcih would make this example more tricky (you'd need a test to see if the text was a valid `int`, or in this case, move the body into the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have alluded to the fact that writing `x == false` and `x == true` are bad style.  There are three reasons for this:

- Conciseness: assuming that you are in a context where a Boolean is required, and "x" is a Boolean, it is less characters to write `x` than `x == true`, or `!x` than `x == false`.
- Convention: seasoned programmers in Java (or C, C++, C# and most other languages) expect to see `x` rather than `x == true`, and `!x` rather than `x == false`.
- Robustness: in Java the conditional and loop statements all require a Boolean valued expression in the condition.  If `y` is not a Boolean, then a typo of the form `if (y = foo) {` will give a compilation error in Java.  But if `y` is a Boolean then `if (y = foo) {` does not give a compilation error.  Hence, by avoiding `==` for Booleans you avoid setting yourself up for a whole raft of bugs resulting from typos.

Answer (score 0):

Many have already pointed out your misuse of `=` vs. `==`.  I would like to point out that running a static code analysis tool like [Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) would have found this for you right away.

See [QBA: Method assigns boolean literal in boolean expression](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#QBA_QUESTIONABLE_BOOLEAN_ASSIGNMENT)